# Spring prototype bean state & thread safety

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I'm working on a project and there is such piece of code:

```
public abstract class Abstract_Mail {

@Value("${general.Mail.sAddressDefaultFrom}")
private String sFrom; 
@Value("${general.Mail.sAddressNoreply}")
private String saTo; 
private String sToName; 
private String sHead = "Subject";
private String sBody = "Text";
@Value("${general.Mail.sUsername}")
private String sAuthUser; //"user";
@Value("${general.Mail.sPassword}")
private String sAuthPassword; //"password";
@Value("${general.Mail.sHost}")
private String sHost; //"gmail.com";
@Value("${general.Mail.nPort}")
private Integer nPort; //Integer.valueOf(mailServerPort);
@Value("${general.Mail.bUseSSL}")
private boolean bSSL;
@Value("${general.Mail.bUseTLS}")
private boolean bTLS;
public Abstract_Mail() {
}

public String getFrom() {
    return sFrom;
}

public Abstract_Mail _From(String sFrom) {
    this.sFrom = sFrom;
    return this;
}

public String getTo() {
    String[] adress = saTo.split("\\,");
    if (adress.length == 1 && sToName != null && 
    !"null".equalsIgnoreCase(sToName)) {
        return sToName + "<" + saTo + ">";
    }
    return saTo;
}

public Abstract_Mail _To(String saTo) {
    this.saTo = saTo;
    return this;
}

public String getToName() {
    return sToName;
}

public Abstract_Mail _ToName(String ... saToName){
    String fullName = saToName[0];
    if (saToName.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < saToName.length; i++) {
            fullName = fullName + " " + saToName[i];
        }
    }
    this.sToName = fullName;
    return this;
}

public String getHead() {
    return sHead;
}

public Abstract_Mail _Head(String sHead) {
    this.sHead = sHead;
    return this;
}

public String getBody() {
    return sBody;
}

public Abstract_Mail _Body(String sBody) {
    this.sBody = sBody;
    return this;
}

public String getAuthUser() {
    return sAuthUser;
}

public Abstract_Mail _AuthUser(String sAuthUser) {
    this.sAuthUser = sAuthUser;
    return this;
}

public String getAuthPassword() {
    return sAuthPassword;
}

public Abstract_Mail _AuthPassword(String sAuthPassword) {
    this.sAuthPassword = sAuthPassword;
    return this;
}

public String getHost() {
    return sHost;
}

public Abstract_Mail _Host(String sHost) {
    this.sHost = sHost;
    return this;
}

public Integer getPort() {
    return nPort;
}

public Abstract_Mail _Port(Integer nPort) {
    this.nPort = nPort;
    return this;
}

public boolean isSSL() {
    return bSSL;
}

public Abstract_Mail _SSL(boolean bSSL) {
    this.bSSL = bSSL;
    return this;
}

public boolean isTLS() {
    return bTLS;
}

public Abstract_Mail _TLS(boolean bTLS) {
    this.bTLS = bTLS;
    return this;
}

abstract public void send() throws Exception;
```

}

And:

```
@Service("mail")
@Scope("prototype")
public class Mail extends Abstract_Mail {

@Autowired
MethodsCallRunnerUtil methodCallRunner;

@Autowired
GeneralConfig generalConfig;

@Autowired
UniSender oUniSender;


private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Mail.class);
private static final Logger LOG_BIG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("MailBig");

Properties oProps = new Properties();
String DEFAULT_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
private Session oSession = null;
//private String sContext="";
private Multipart oMultiparts = new MimeMultipart();

public Mail() {
}

@Override
public void send() throws EmailException {
    LOG.info("send mail started...");
    LOG.info("(getFrom()={})", getFrom());
    LOG.info("(getTo()={})", getTo());
    String sTo = getTo();
    String sToNew = sTo;
    sToNew = sToNew.replace("\"", "");
    sToNew = sToNew.replace("\"", "");
    if (!sToNew.equals(sTo)) {
        LOG.info("(getTo()(fixed)={})", sToNew);
        _To(sToNew);
    }
    LOG.info("(getHead()={})", getHead());

    Boolean bUniSender = generalConfig.isEnable_UniSender_Mail();
    LOG.info("(bUniSender={})", bUniSender);
    LOG_BIG.info("(bUniSender={})", bUniSender);
    LOG_BIG.debug("(getFrom()={})", getFrom());
    LOG_BIG.debug("(getTo()={})", getTo());
    LOG_BIG.debug("(getHead()={})", getHead());
    LOG_BIG.debug("(getBody={})", getBody());

    StringBuilder sbBody = new StringBuilder(500);
    sbBody.append("host: ");
    sbBody.append(getHost());
    sbBody.append(":");
    sbBody.append(getPort());
    sbBody.append("\nAuthUser:");
    sbBody.append(getAuthUser());
    sbBody.append("\nfrom:");
    sbBody.append(getFrom());
    sbBody.append("\nto:");
    sbBody.append(getTo());
    sbBody.append("\nhead:");
    sbBody.append(getHead());

    if (bUniSender) {
        try {
            if (!sendWithUniSender()) {
                sendAlternativeWay(sbBody.toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception oException) {
            LOG.warn("Try send via alter channel! (getTo()={})", 
    oException.getMessage(), getTo());
            LOG.trace("FAIL:", oException);
            try {
                //msgService.setEventSystem("WARNING", null, null, 
    "sendWithUniSender", "Error send via UniSender", sbBody.toString(), 
    oException.getMessage(), null);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            sendAlternativeWay(sbBody.toString());
        }
    } else {
        sendAlternativeWay(sbBody.toString());
    }

    LOG.info("send mail ended ehith sbBody: " + sbBody.toString());
}

public void sendOld() throws EmailException {
    LOG.info("sendOld started...");
    LOG.info("init");
    try {
        MultiPartEmail oMultiPartEmail = new MultiPartEmail();
        LOG.info("(getHost()={})", getHost());
        oMultiPartEmail.setHostName(getHost());

        String[] asTo = { sMailOnly(getTo()) };
        if (getTo().contains("\\,")) {
            asTo = getTo().split("\\,");//sTo
            for (String s : asTo) {
                LOG.info("oMultiPartEmail.addTo (s={})", s);
                oMultiPartEmail.addTo(s, "receiver");
            }
        }

        LOG.info("(getFrom()={})", getFrom());
        LOG_BIG.debug("(getFrom()={})", getFrom());
        oMultiPartEmail.setFrom(getFrom(), getFrom());//"iGov"
        oMultiPartEmail.setSubject(getHead());
        LOG.info("getHead()={}", getHead());
        String sLogin = getAuthUser();
        if (sLogin != null && !"".equals(sLogin.trim())) {
            oMultiPartEmail.setAuthentication(sLogin, getAuthPassword());
            LOG.info("withAuth");
        } else {
            LOG.info("withoutAuth");
        }
        //oMultiPartEmail.setAuthentication(getAuthUser(), getAuthPassword());
        LOG.info("(getAuthUser()={})", getAuthUser());
        //LOG.info("getAuthPassword()=" + getAuthPassword());
        oMultiPartEmail.setSmtpPort(getPort());
        LOG.info("(getPort()={})", getPort());
        oMultiPartEmail.setSSL(isSSL());
        LOG.info("(isSSL()={})", isSSL());
        oMultiPartEmail.setTLS(isTLS());
        LOG.info("(isTLS()={})", isTLS());

        oSession = oMultiPartEmail.getMailSession();
        MimeMessage oMimeMessage = new MimeMessage(oSession);

        LOG.info("oMimeMessage oSession: " +  oSession);

        //oMimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(getFrom(), "iGov", DEFAULT_ENCODING));
        oMimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(getFrom(), getFrom()));
        //oMimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(sTo, sToName, DEFAULT_ENCODING));

        LOG.info("oMimeMessage From: " + getFrom());

        String sReceiverName = "receiver";
        if (asTo.length == 1) {
            sReceiverName = getToName();
        }
        for (String s : asTo) {
            LOG.info("oMimeMessage.addRecipient (s={})", s);
            //oMultiPartEmail.addTo(s, "receiver");
            oMimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(s, sReceiverName, DEFAULT_ENCODING));
        }

        //oMimeMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        //        new InternetAddress(sTo, "recipient", DEFAULT_ENCODING));
        //new InternetAddress(getTo(), "recipient", DEFAULT_ENCODING));
        oMimeMessage.setSubject(getHead(), DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        LOG.info("oMimeMessage head: " + getHead());

        _AttachBody(getBody());
        LOG.info("(getBody()={})", getBody());
        oMimeMessage.setContent(oMultiparts);
        LOG.info("oMimeMessage content: " + oMimeMessage.getContent().toString());
        //            oMimeMessage.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC);
        //methodCallRunner.registrateMethod(Transport.class.getName(), "send", new Object[]{oMimeMessage});

        try{

            Transport.send(oMimeMessage);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            LOG.info("There are some eroor during mail transport: " + ex);
        }

        LOG.info("Mail was transported....");
        LOG.info("Send " + getTo() + "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    } catch (Exception oException) {
        LOG.error("FAIL: {} (getTo()={})", oException.getMessage(), getTo());
        LOG.trace("FAIL:", oException);
        throw new EmailException("Error happened when sending email (" + getTo() + ")"
                + "Exception message: " + oException.getMessage(), oException);
    }
    LOG.info("SUCCESS: Sent!");
    LOG.info("sendOld ended...");
}

public Mail _AttachBody(String sBody) {
    try {
        MimeBodyPart oMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        //oMimeBodyPart.setText(sBody,DEFAULT_ENCODING,"Content-Type: text/html;");
        oMimeBodyPart.setText(sBody, DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        //         oMimeBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        oMimeBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        oMultiparts.addBodyPart(oMimeBodyPart);
        LOG.info("sBodylength()={}", sBody != null ? sBody.length() : "null");
    } catch (Exception oException) {
        LOG.error("FAIL:", oException);
    }
    return this;
}

public Mail _Attach(File oFile) {
    _Attach(new FileDataSource(oFile), oFile.getName(), "");
    return this;
}

public Mail _Attach(File[] aFile) {
    LOG.info("(aFile.length={})", aFile.length);
    for (File oFile : aFile) {
        _Attach(oFile);
    }
    return this;
}

public Mail _Attach(DataSource oDataSource, String sFileName, String sDescription) {
    LOG.info("_Attach started..");
    try {
        MimeBodyPart oMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        oMimeBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");
        oMimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(oDataSource));
        oMimeBodyPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(sFileName));
        oMultiparts.addBodyPart(oMimeBodyPart);
        LOG.info("(sFileName={}, sDescription={})", sFileName, sDescription);
    } catch (Exception oException) {
        LOG.error("FAIL: {} (sFileName={},sDescription={})", oException.getMessage(), sFileName, sDescription);
        LOG.trace("FAIL:", oException);
    }
    LOG.info("_Attach ended..");
    return this;
}

public Mail _Attach(URL[] aoURL) {
    return _Attach(aoURL, null);
}

public Mail _Attach(URL[] aoURL, String[] asName) {
    LOG.info("(asName={})", asName);
    for (int n = 0; n < aoURL.length; n++) {
        try {
            if (asName == null) {
                _Attach(aoURL[n], null);
            } else {
                _Attach(aoURL[n], asName[n]);
            }
        } catch (Exception oException) {
            LOG.error("FAIL:", oException);
        }
    }
    return this;
}

public Mail _Attach(URL oURL, String sName) {
    try {
        MimeBodyPart oMimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();//javax.activation
        oMimeBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");
        DataSource oDataSource = new URLDataSource(oURL);
        oMimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(oDataSource));
        //oPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(source.getName()));
        oMimeBodyPart.setFileName(
                MimeUtility.encodeText(sName == null || "".equals(sName) ? oDataSource.getName() : sName));
        oMultiparts.addBodyPart(oMimeBodyPart);
        LOG.info("(sName={})", sName);
    } catch (Exception oException) {
        LOG.error("FAIL: {} (sName={})", oException.getMessage(), sName);
        LOG.trace("FAIL:", oException);
    }
    return this;
}

public static String sMailOnly(String sMail) {
    String sMailNew = sMail;
    try {
        if (sMailNew.contains("<")) {
            String[] asMail = sMailNew.split("\\<");
            sMailNew = asMail[1];
            asMail = sMailNew.split("\\>");
            sMailNew = asMail[0];
        }
    } catch (Exception oException) {
        LOG.warn("FAIL: {} (sMail={},sMailNew={})", oException.getMessage(), sMail, sMailNew);
    }
    return sMailNew;
}

//public void sendWithUniSender() throws EmailException {
public boolean sendWithUniSender() {
    LOG.info("Init...");
    boolean result = true;
    Object oID_Message = null;
    StringBuilder sbBody = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        sbBody.append("host: ");
        sbBody.append(getHost());
        sbBody.append(":");
        sbBody.append(getPort());
        sbBody.append("\nAuthUser:");
        sbBody.append(getAuthUser());
        sbBody.append("\nfrom:");
        sbBody.append(getFrom());
        sbBody.append("\nto:");
        sbBody.append(getTo());
        sbBody.append("\nhead:");
        sbBody.append(getHead());

        String sKey_Sender = generalConfig.getKey_UniSender_Mail();
        long nID_Sender = generalConfig.getSendListId_UniSender_Mail();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(sKey_Sender)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please check api_key in UniSender property file configuration");
        }

        LOG.info("oUniSender - {}", oUniSender);
        LOG.info("methodCallRunner - {}", methodCallRunner);
        oUniSender.setMethodCallRunner(methodCallRunner);

        if (getTo().contains(",")) {
            String[] asMail = getTo().split("\\,");
            for (String sMail : asMail) {
                sMail = sMailOnly(sMail);
                UniResponse oUniResponse_Subscribe = oUniSender
                        .subscribe(Collections.singletonList(String.valueOf(nID_Sender)), sMail, getToName());
                LOG.info("(sMail={},oUniResponse_Subscribe={})", sMail, oUniResponse_Subscribe);
            }
        } else {
            String sMail = sMailOnly(getTo());
            UniResponse oUniResponse_Subscribe = oUniSender
                    .subscribe(Collections.singletonList(String.valueOf(nID_Sender)), sMail, getToName());
            LOG.info("(oUniResponse_Subscribe={})", oUniResponse_Subscribe);
        }

        String sBody =  getBody();
        //sBody = sBody + "" + "<br>Для отписки перейдите по <a href=\"{{UnsubscribeUrl}}\">ссылке</a>";
        sBody = sBody + "" + "<br>Якщо Ви бажаєте відмовитися від повідомлень, будь ласка, натисніть <a href=\"{{UnsubscribeUrl}}\"тут</a>/";

        CreateEmailMessageRequest.Builder oBuilder = CreateEmailMessageRequest
                //.getBuilder(sKey_Sender, "en")
                .getBuilder(sKey_Sender, "ua")
                .setSenderName("no reply")
                .setSenderEmail(getFrom())
                .setSubject(getHead())
                .setBody(sBody)
                .setListId(String.valueOf(nID_Sender));

        try {
            int nAttachments = oMultiparts.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < nAttachments; i++) {
                BodyPart oBodyPart = oMultiparts.getBodyPart(i);
                String sFileName = oBodyPart.getFileName();
                InputStream oInputStream = oBodyPart.getInputStream();
                oBuilder.setAttachment(sFileName, oInputStream);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception("Error while getting attachment.", e);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new Exception("Error while getting attachment.", e);
        }

        CreateEmailMessageRequest oCreateEmailMessageRequest = oBuilder.build();

        UniResponse oUniResponse_CreateEmailMessage = oUniSender.createEmailMessage(oCreateEmailMessageRequest);
        LOG.info("(oUniResponse_CreateEmailMessage={})", oUniResponse_CreateEmailMessage);

        if (oUniResponse_CreateEmailMessage != null && oUniResponse_CreateEmailMessage.getResult() != null) {
            Map<String, Object> mParam = oUniResponse_CreateEmailMessage.getResult();
            LOG.info("(mParam={})", mParam);
            oID_Message = mParam.get("message_id");
            if (oID_Message != null) {
                LOG.info("(oID_Message={})", oID_Message);
                CreateCampaignRequest oCreateCampaignRequest = CreateCampaignRequest.getBuilder(sKey_Sender, "en")
                        .setMessageId(oID_Message.toString())
                        .build();

                UniResponse oUniResponse_CreateCampaign = oUniSender
                        .createCampaign(oCreateCampaignRequest, getTo());
                LOG.info("(oUniResponse_CreateCampaign={})", oUniResponse_CreateCampaign);
            } else {
                result = false;
                LOG.error("error while email creation " + oUniResponse_CreateEmailMessage.getError());
                //throw new EmailException("error while email creation " + oUniResponse_CreateEmailMessage.getError());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception oException) {
        result = false;
        LOG.error("FAIL: {} (oID_Message()={},getTo()={})", oException.getMessage(), oID_Message, getTo());
        new Log(oException, LOG)
                ._Case("Mail_FailUS")
                ._Status(Log.LogStatus.ERROR)
                ._Head("First try send fail")
                ._Param("getTo", getTo())
                ._Param("sbBody", sbBody)
                ._Param("oID_Message", oID_Message)
                .save()
        ;
    }
    LOG.info("SUCCESS: sent!");
    return result;
}

private void sendAlternativeWay(String sbBody) {
    LOG.info("sendAlternativeWay started...");
    try {
        sendOld();
    } catch (Exception oException1) {
            new Log(oException1, LOG)//this.getClass()
                    ._Case("Mail_FailAlter")
                    ._Status(Log.LogStatus.ERROR)
                    ._Head("Final send trying fail")
                    //._Body(oException1.getMessage())
                    ._Param("getTo", getTo())
                    ._Param("sbBody", sbBody)
                    .save()
            ;
    }
    LOG.info("sendAlternativeWay ended...");
}

}
```

**Client class** lokks like this:

```
SomeController {

@Autowired
Mail mail;

sendTo() {
  mail.setTo("Some address");
  mail.set....
  mail.set....
  mail.set....
  mail.send();
 }
}
```

As far as I know **Prototype scope** means that bean is created "each time it is injected". Thus each time we request **sendTo()** of **SomeController** we change state of the same **Mail** and get **race condition**. Isn't it right?

P.S
I've added such a lot of code cause I thought maybe there are some datails making this approach sensible.

Comment: Far too much code. Reduce it to a minimal example containing just what is needed to understand your question. And make that example respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Your expectations are right about the same Mail instance inside that Controller